# Ebook reader for my website

Tags: html, css

I am building a literature website that contains original works. However, first focus groups said that some texts like short stories(5k to 10k words) is very long and they will probably read in a few parts, but it is hard to track where you have left without a paging system.

I am trying to implement a ebook reader like system. That is, I want to make a slideshow of texts in a sense. But I don't want to use pdf.

So here is how it should work: based on the device the code should set the page fitting your screen and enumerate; and there should be two "arrows", one on left one on right, for changing the page.
A standardized page size would also work.

The idea is simple enough but I have trouble implementing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why the down vote people? I am not a programmer or anything, I am trying to learn and read from different sources but couldn't find what I am looking for. If it is impossible, say that. If it is very simple say that as well but this is of no use to anyone.

Comment: Because you haven't shown any attempt to solve the problem. Even a basic attempt will usually be enough. Otherwise people think you are being lazy and expecting free code.

Also are you wanting a backend or frontend solution or a mix of both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best ebbok readers for websites is Monocle. [Here](http://monocle.inventivelabs.com.au) This lets you run a book reader from your website.